# Automorphism group of alternating group.

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, automorphism-group

As we know $\operatorname{Aut}(A_n)\cong \operatorname{Aut}(S_n)\cong S_n$ for $n\geq4$, $n\neq 6$ and $\operatorname{Aut}(A_6)\cong \operatorname{Aut}(S_6)\cong S_6\rtimes C_2$.

1. Is there any method to obtain an element $g$ in $S_n$ ($n\neq 6$) for $f\in \operatorname{Aut}(S_n)$ so that $f$ is the conjugation map by $g$?
2. Another problem is that if $H$ is subgroup of $A_6$ and $\sigma\in\operatorname{Aut}(A_6)$ then are the subgroups $H$ and $\sigma(H)$ conjugate in $S_6$?  Also what can we say about $H$ and $\sigma(H)$ if $n\neq 6$?

Comment: For the first problem, how is your $f$ given?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft $f$ is an automorphism of $S_n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question, compute $f$ on the $n$-cycle $(12\dots n)$ to obtain $(a_{1} a_{2} \dots a_{n})$. Then compute $f$ on the $2$-cycle $(12)$ to obtain $(b_{1} b_{2})$. Now within the $a_{i}$ there are two consecutive ones (indices are taken modulo $n$) such that

1. $a_{i} = b_{1}, a_{i+1} = b_{2}$, or
2. $a_{i} = b_{2}, a_{i+1} = b_{1}$.

Your $g$ is
$$
1 \mapsto a_{i}, 2 \mapsto a_{i+1}, \dots , n \mapsto a_{n+i-1},
$$
where here, too, indices are taken modulo $n$.

--

**Explanation** Recall that 
$$
(12\dots n) = (1^{g} 2^{g} \dots n^{g}),
$$
where $i^{g}$ indicates the image of $i$ under the permutation $g$. So if $f$ is the same thing as conjugation by $g$, computing the image of $(12\dots n)$, under $f$ will give you one of
$$
(1^{g} 2^{g} \dots n^{g}) = (2^{g} \dots n^{g} 1^{g}) = (3^{g} \dots n^{g} 1^{g} 2^{g}) = \dots
$$
To see what the images of $1$ under $g$ is, compute $f$ on $(12)$.

Comment: Lovely $g{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @BabakS., thanks, that's very kind of you!

Comment: Thanks @AndreasCaranti. As I asked you told the method. I am now trying to verify it (but unable to prove). Also looking for answers of other parts. Please help.

Comment: @user93432, I'm adding an explanation in 3.. 2.. 1..

Comment: Another method (not worth an answer, since there are two questions anyway) is to compute $f(1 i)$ for each $i\neq 1$. Two different $i$ will yield $(a b)$ and $(a c)$: $a$ is $g(1)$ and now for any $i$, $f(1 i)= (a c)$ means $g(i) = c$

Answer (score 1):

For second question, I think it is not true.
for example take $H=\langle (1,2,3)\rangle$ and there is a $\sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(A_6)$ such that $\sigma(H)=\langle (1,2,3)(4,5,6)\rangle$ but $H$ and $\sigma(H)$ are not conjugate. And for third question, I think it is true because all automorphisms of $A_n$ ($n\neq 6$) are conjugation by elements of $S_n$. (Please correct if there is any mistake).